# Merge/Sort Array by Name

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I try to sort an array by name. I want to create a structure similar to a menu. First, I allow a function to write values into the array. Then I would like to assign all subpages to the parent (resulting from the structure, such as a URL).
Out

```
array
(
     [0] => array
         (
             [Pages] => coreViewSites
         )

     [1] => array
         (
             [Pages / Create] => create coreView
         )

     [2] => array
         (
             [Pages / Duplicate] => coreViewSites
         )

     [3] => array
         (
             [Pages / Anarchy] => coreViewSites
         )

     [4] => array
         (
             [User] => coreViewUser
         )

)
```

should an array like

```
array
(
     [Pages] => Array
         (
             [0] => ABC
             [Create] => ABC
             [Duplicate] => ABC
             [Anarchy] => ABC
         )

     [User] => ABC
)
```

become.

Do you have an idea how I could solve this?

Comment: Where is your best coding attempt?  Please only use synchronized sample input and desired output for 100% clarity.  Do you _need_ recursion or is your input data predictably "flat" (never more than 2 levels deep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the menu items are ordered with parents coming before children, here is how you could do that:

```
$menu = [];
foreach($input as $path) {
    $keys = explode(" / ", key($path)); // Extract the individual menu titles
    $last = array_pop($keys); // Pull the last one from it
    $loc = &$menu;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        // Create menu item if it does not exist yet
        if (!isset($loc[$key])) $loc[$key] = []; 
        // When a menu gets sub-menu, move the title in index 0 of a new array
        if (!is_array($loc[$key])) $loc[$key] = [$loc[$key]];
        $loc = &$loc[$key]; // Set the pointer to that submenu
    }
    $loc[$last] = reset($path); // At the deepest level assign the menu title.
}
// Print result:
var_export($menu);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Pages' => array (
        0 => 'coreViewSites',
        'Create' => 'create coreView',
        'Duplicate' => 'coreViewSites',
        'Anarchy' => 'coreViewSites',
    ),
    'User' => 'coreViewUser',
)
```